# How to get data from service and database and send post data to server?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I'm using RestTemplate JSON to get data from service and database, and then send POST to server. I have tested on Postmen and it get result 200

My format json:

```
{
"senderUser": "myemail@gmail.com",
"data": [
    {
        "actionType": "update-contact",
        "data": {
            "name": "NakiTa  ",
            "lastname": "Isumi",
            "type": 0,
            "title": "ms",
            "passport": "123123",
            "gender": 1,
            "dateOfBirth": "03-01-2021",
            "emails": [
                {
                    "value": "test@gmail.com"
                }
            ],
            "phones": [
                {
                    "value": "0902032618"
                }
            ],
            "addresses": [
                {
                    "addressDetail": "Osaka",
                    "street": "Osaka",
                    "city": "Osaka",
                    "state": "JP",
                    "country": {
                        "code": "jp",
                        "name": "Japan"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "cusFields": [
                {
                    "600f9cb0f02f084bd8a3dcdb": "TEST"
                }                    
            ],
            "customerType": "company"               
        }
    }
]
}
```

My class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAllCustomerBasic.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<MyClassMap>> getAllCustomerBasic(@RequestParam Map<String, Object> params,
      HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

LOGGER.debug("groupCode : {}", params.get("custId"));

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonHttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
jsonHttpMessageConverter.getObjectMapper().configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(jsonHttpMessageConverter);

String url = "https://myservice/6670011cbd4a674458d3b26025/90336429462601e7f3326641898fabd9948b349d";
List<MyClassMap> customerList = customerService.getAllCustomerViewBasicInfo(params);            // .selectAccBank(params);

try {

    JSONArray arrayParent = new JSONArray();
    for(int i=0 ; i<customerList.size() ; i++) {
        arrayParent.put(customerList.get(i));
    }

    JSONObject objectParent = new JSONObject();
    objectParent.put("data", arrayParent);

    JSONObject objectChild = new JSONObject();
    objectChild.put("senderUser", "myemail@gmail.com");

    JSONObject objectChildData = new JSONObject();
    objectChildData.put("actionType", "update-contact");

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
    headers.add("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(objectParent.toString(), headers);
    String result = restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, String.class);

    LOGGER.info(result);
    LOGGER.info("header: " + entity.getHeaders());
    LOGGER.info("body" + entity.getBody());
}

catch (HttpClientErrorException exception) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    exception.printStackTrace();
}

return ResponseEntity.ok(customerList);         // customerList   jSONObject
}
```

With customerService will get data from database success but I When I build and check data it seem happen an exception follow as:

```
body{"data":{}}
```

it seem get data is null and can not get all data. How to fix the problem ? many thank

Answer (score 0):

RestTemplate makes the serialization to json automatically. You only have to define a Java Class with the same attributes (and with the same type) the API expects and in the postForObject method indicate that the object is the same as your class instead a String.class.

For example, if your MyClassMap data have the same attributes as the elements in the data json array, it could be:

```
//You have to add getters and setters and constructor
public Class Request {
  private String senderUser;
  private List<MyClassMap> data;
}

ClassRequest request= new ClassRequest();
request.setData(customerList);
request.setSenderUser("example");
HttpEntity<ClassRequest> entity = new HttpEntity<ClassRequest>(request, headers);

String result = restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, ClassRequest.class);
```

Comment: Hi @JArgente, will I have to create new class similar to POJO as you said ?

Comment: or could you give me more detail ?

Comment: Yes you have to create POJO classes that matches the structure of the json you want to send and spring will serialize it to json with the help of jackson library without need of any other code

Comment: So, your meaning I don't use jackson as Jsonobject and jsonarray

Comment: thats it, I think the problem you have is because doing it manually you probably have made some mistakes and the process is more tedious, for example, as I can see you are putting thesenderUser attribute as an attribute of objectchild, but I should be an attribute of objectParent as it is in the same level as data. Also you are adding actionType attribute as part of objectChildData object that you are not using in the code...